# Configure Avast Free from command line

Tags: avast

Is there a way to configure Avast Antivirus from command line?

What I want to do is add my application to the exception list, when it is being installed on my clients. Most clients don't know how to do this and add it to the virus chest. This causes serious problems as we need to manually connect to each one having the problem and add it to the exception list.

The reason my application seems dangerous is because it is uses internal stuff of windows and seems like a suspect.

I am interested in solutions applied to all versions of windows (Xp to 8).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Here's the Avast Knowledge Base article about command line switches : https://support.avast.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1240</strike>

But there isn't a command line switch which will let you add your file to an exception list and for good reasons; what's stopping the malicious programs to add themselves in the exception list if a command line switch like that is available.

See comments for the correct answer.

Comment: This is for the Avast setup. Not the installed application.

Comment: I apologgise. It looks like i made too many mistakes yesterday. Anyway, here's the correct link, and it seems that you can move the file to Virus Chest.
http://avast.helpmax.net/en/command-line-scanner/command-line-parameters/
Anyway,